# Function isn't writing to database?

Tags: php, themoviedb-api

I'm trying to fetch some data from [The Movie Database](https://www.themoviedb.org), using a [library](https://github.com/php-tmdb/api) to insert results in a database locally using Xampp.

Here's what I have so far, I know it's dirty (globals in functions and such) but I'm running this locally - I just need it to write data to the DB if there is any valid data, or rerun the function if not.

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$token  = new \Tmdb\ApiToken('My API Key - removed');
$client = new \Tmdb\Client($token);
$mid = 1;
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

moviedetails();

function moviedetails() {

    global $token;
    global $client;
    global $mid;
    global $conn;

    $repository = new \Tmdb\Repository\MovieRepository($client);
    $movie = $client->getMoviesApi()->getMovie($mid);

    var_dump($movie);

        $votecount = $movie['vote_count'];
        $voteaverage = $movie['vote_average'];
        $image = $movie['poster_path'];
        $releasedate = $movie['release_date'];
        $id = $movie['id'];
        $title = $movie['title'];
        $description = $movie['overview'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO movie (votes, vote_average, poster, release_date, dbid, title, description)
        VALUES ('$votecount', '$voteaverage', '$image', '$releasedate', '$id', '$title', '$description')";

        echo $mid;

        $mid++;
        moviedetails();

}
```

My script fails when `$mid` = 3, but hasn't written the other two valid entries to my database.

Comment: It could be a quoting issue. Save yourself the headache, and switch to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).  Also, I don't see where you actually insert the sql into the database.

Comment: You are not actaully inserting to the database, you just have a query prepared to do it, there is no execution of that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actaully inserting to the database, you just have a query prepared to do it, there is no execution of that query.

You need `$conn->query($sql)` after your `$sql = "query"` .

Comment: Cheers for that, haven't used PHP in quite a while

Comment: glad I could help, going forward and making sure you've adapted to latest practices in php (as older ones are found to be insecure and/or are quickly becoming depreciated), I would also recommend you learn and resort to prepared statement for all your needs, as suggested by aynber in a comment above with a link to a resource.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your concern. I would use prepared statements for production code, but this is being run in a VM using Xampp for a sample test - I'm not too concerned if something happens to the data as it's a new DB. But I do agree, and appreciate the concern!

Answer (score 0):

Global $mid . Also must in top scrpit .